# How can I model the multivariate probability distribution of a dataset with both continuous and discrete variables for sampling?

Tags: distributions, python, sampling, conditional-probability, synthetic-data

This might seem like a duplicate of the following link, but I think that one is asking how to create a completely new dataset with specific distributions, rather than how to model an existing dataset distribution.

[How do you create a multivariate distribution with both continuous and discrete data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43520/how-do-you-create-a-multivariate-distribution-with-both-continuous-and-discrete)

**Problem**

I have a dataset containing a mixture of continuous and discrete columns, which are all dependent on one another, so it's a multivariate distribution with both continuous and discrete variables.

I want to model the distribution so that new/synthetic data points can be sampled from it. Ideally this would be done using existing Python libraries, but if this is not possible I'll give it a go in Python myself.

**Solution that I can't use**

There is a solution to this, and it involves using GANs to train a model that understands the distribution of the dataset. It's possible to do this in Python with `Synthetic Data Vault`. Unfortunately, I don't have GPU capabilities yet, and have too much data to train these GANs without a GPU. Hence the following...

**Continuous data**

If I had a multivariate distribution of continuous data, I would typically use something like sklearn's `KernelDensity` class to model the distribution and easily sample from it.

**Discrete data**

With discrete data, you could set up a probability mass function and sample from it with something like `random.choices()` in Python.

**Combining continuous and discrete**

However, I'm a bit stuck with datasets that are a combination of the two. I don't think `KernelDensity` is strictly valid for discrete variables, and I'm not sure how probability mass functions can be sampled from for multivariate data.

I'm hoping there is a solution that allows for some kind of Bayesian modelling of the relationships between different columns across rows which leads to the ability to set up a conditional distribution and sample from it. But I'm not sure, can't find any online, and have ended up here for help.

Comment: Re "I'm not sure how probability mass functions can be sampled from for multivariate data:" the same way they are sampled from univariate data, because each possible combination has a definite probability.  What is lacking here is any indication of the possible models you might be contemplating applying to this extremely general question, so adding some specifics about that to this post would be helpful.

Comment: @whuber I don't really see how it's overly general. It's equivalent to asking "What are popular approaches to modelling a distribution of data containing both continuous and discrete variables, and do Python packages exist for those methods?" Perhaps muddled with my thoughts. I fail to see how that's too general, but happy to be corrected/

Comment: It is far too general, because it explicitly asks for a list of possible replies to an open, broad question.

Comment: @whuber there's only one way to interpret the question though - how is that broad? Also, are we only supposed to ask questions that have a single solution? If yes then fine, as ridiculous as that would be. Fine, there may be multiple possible answers, but they would be answers that are either right or wrong.

Comment: "Broad" does not mean "ambiguous."  Questions should be sufficiently narrow and focused that they are likely, by their form, to have one *correct* answer.  It would be worth your while to read some of the more popular posts on our meta site about asking questions, as well as to tour our help system.  If you still find the premises of the site "ridiculous," then the best solution for you might be to spend your time elsewhere.